# Old bitcoin wallet not working

Tags: bitcoin-core

So Im having a bit of a problem with my bitcoin wallet. See, I got into bitcoin about 2 years ago, back when bitcoins were worth very little real money, if any at all, but I managed to get quite a few. I recently found out they were getting bigger, so I tried to open bitcoin with my wallet, but it crashed, so I moved it from my mac to my PC. It said it was something like 200 weeks behind, so I waited, and now when its finally done, it says I have no bitcoins, but Im sure this wallet had some. Any ideas of how to get them back?

I tried getting my wallet onto blockchain, but I always get the error-
Unexpected end of file from server

Also, in my bitcoin qt, I dont actually have any addresses

Comment: By the sounds of it you either didn't copy the `wallet.dat` from your Mac properly (it made a new empty one instead) or didn't copy it fully (end of file means it only got half the wallet). Either way you certainly don't have a workable wallet on your PC now, do you have another backup of your `wallet.dat`? Otherwise your options are severely limited.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Any ideas? Did anything work?

Comment: Install new client into your Mac from bitcoin.org it wouldn't replace or delete the previous wallet.dat and you will be able to access it.

Comment: Do you have Time Machine backups?  Restore an older backup of ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout pywallet. Its a python script that may be able to help you out. I've had similar issues with OSX clients in the past. You may also want to try finding an older version of the bitcoin-qt client for OSX and see if that works.

https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could have happened is that you got into sync on the wrong fork of the network. This happens sometimes - they make a new fork of the network, and if you don't upgrade your client before you hit a certain block your wallet is screwed. Almost happened to my DogeCoin wallet once.

To make sure you copied the wallet.dat correctly, on your Mac, go to Finder. Hit <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. Enter `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin`. Take the file `wallet.dat` and copy it onto a memory stick. On your Windows box, make sure Bitcoin is not running, hit <kbd>win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and type in `explorer %APPDATA%\Bitcoin`. Delete everything in there, and copy in your `wallet.dat`. Launch up the latest version of Bitcoin, wait for it to get in sync, and then you should have your coins back, or at least most of them, depending on how many confirmations the transactions originally had.

If that doesn't work, your wallet is probably screwed. Bad luck :-(